# Forcing Bundle Workflow Process on Components | Workflow Process hasTranslation functionality

Tags: 2013-sp1, workflow, translation-manager

So we wanted to force Components into workflow before any changes are made to them. For this we use the checkbox “Any changes made to a Component based on this Schema require approval by a Bundle Workflow Process” in the Component Schema as shown below:

[image]

It works as expected and forces the component to the Bundle Workflow Process before it can be approved but it exposes an issue which is related to translation.

We support Translation in our workflow process and there is a “Send For Translation” workflow activity for this. This activity creates a translation job of type “Push” and sends items for translation. when the job is sent, the component is localized and checked-out in target publications. When the translation is retrieved by the translation management system it's checked back in. *(This works like this when the above checkbox is unchecked in schema)*

Now when we force Bundle Workflow Process on Components using the checkbox shown above, after completion of translation, the component is *NOT* localized with the local content in the target publication.

We're wondering if this is because when TMS tries to localize the component, it can’t because Tridion expects the component to be locked by a “Bundle Workflow Process”. And so the component is not localized and remains untranslated.

We have tried below options to make this work:

1. Localize the schema at local publication level and uncheck the checkbox

   This works, but it would mean we need to localize all the schemas at translation target publication level (of which there are many publications for many clients). Also, we need to take care of syncing the schema from the parent if any change happens at the parent publication.
2. Disable workflow for local Publication

   This works but we need workflow at the target level so can't go with this approach.

Can you suggest better options to support translation with the workflow enforcing checkbox?

Comment: "Also, I need to take care of syncing the schema from parent if any change happens at the parent publication." - not necessarily. If the parent has changed to schema fields, the localized versions should still inherit those changes. The only things you can localize are field labels and the workflow on the schema. Hence other core schema things should not be affected.

Comment: Have you checked with SDL Support? It might be a bug.

Comment: Although I agree with Nick - it could well be a bug?

If there's an exception then the logs should show something? Have you checked the verbose Translation logs?

If you can catch the localise event before it fails you may be able to avoid root cause of the fail (i.e. add it to a workflow bundle on the fly) - BUT I suspect this will open a can of works - not least checking if you can even add it before it's localized, the processing for creating bundles etc. on the fly 'v' the time/cost of this when it should be an edge-case given training and documentation)

Comment: With regards _Also, we need to take care of syncing the schema from the parent if any change happens at the parent publication_ - I don't think this is the case. The descriptions _may_ need synching (if editros are expected to open/use these components) but **new fields** will be added, **updated fields** will have their type and/or XML name updated if this is the update (the description will not push down), **removed fields** will be removed. Schema localization is there to allow the _presentation_ to be updated and the technical updates for workflow.

Comment: Thanks Guys for the clarifications about the localizing a schema. I will check the logs and update the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you **do not need** "Bundle workflow" on target items you have to localize schemas and remove this check box in target publications.

But if you **need** "Bundle workflow" on target items there is a hotfix for this problem TT88491

Note that TM is not responsible for deling with workflows that start after translation is done. 
After applying this hotfix TM will check-in translated content and leave target component in "Reserved state" (in bundle workflow).

Answer (score 1):

If you **do not need**, rather than @Yuri's approach, you can use this setting in Publication properties to ignore inherited Workflow settings

[image]

Comment: Thanks Chris, But we need workflow at the local publication so can't switch it off.